# Building polygons and the lines that represent their edges in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I want to create polygons from intersecting lines using QGIS 3, each polygon having a unique ID attribute. In addition to the polygonal areas, I need the lines that represent their edges; each of those lines needs to have attributes that are the ID’s of the polygons that lie to their left and their right. Note that the original lines are often divided into several smaller lines, each with a different pair of ‘left’ and ‘right’ attributes.

See the illustration below to get an idea of what I’m shooting for. Ideally, the next step would be to join consecutive edges that bound the same areas (e.g. the four blue lines that bound areas 0 and 1.

I did this in ARC/INFO 25-30 years ago. I just can’t figure out how to do it in QGIS 3.

[image: “Before” and “after” the operation I’m trying to do.]

Comment: Are you stuck on your step 1?  If so, what have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: What's the purpose of this operation? Why not just have the user digitize polygons from the start?

Comment: Thank you to PolyGeo and csk for their comments. The first step is easy, using ‘Polygonize’ to make the areas, and ‘Split lines with lines’ to make the edges. The problem is identifying the smaller ‘edge’ lines and their left and right polygons. The reason the user can’t simply digitize the polygons is that they may have shared edges (e.g. the green line in my figure). In the computational code that eventually utilizes these geometries, the mathematical conditions depend on the adjacent polygons; I can’t risk the user editing the green edge of Area 1 without the edits also modifying Area 2.

Comment: SAGA, installed with Qgis, has Polygons to Edges and Nodes.

Comment: I’ve tried the SAGA extension, and it runs, but it doesn’t write any output. I can’t find documentation for the extension. I started with a QGIS3 polygon layer, generated by the Polygonize processing tool. Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Some of the SAGA tools don't work recently. You could search the [issue tracker](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues) and see if an issue has been filed for `Polygons to Edges and Nodes`.

Comment: When polygons have shared edges, and moving the edge of one polygon forces the edge of the other polygon to move too, that's called **topology**. I never use topology, but I think you can set it up within a QGIS project in the snapping toolbar. There might also be layer types that allow topology. In ArcGIS, you would use a geodatabase; I'm not sure what the open source equivalent is. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/topologies/topology-in-arcgis.htm https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/topology.html